# How to iterate backwards with a custom iterator in Java using permutations

Tags: java, algorithm, iterator, iteration, permutation

I am trying to create a a class of Permutation that extends Iterator and adds two methods: previous() and hasPrevious().

- It must offer a constructor with one argument: a string containing the ordered sequence of characters from which the permutations will be generated. Invalid parameters should throw an IllegalArgumentException.
- It must offer a constructor with two arguments: a string containing the ordered sequence of characters from which the permutations will be generated, and the starting length of the first permutation. The length of the first permutation must be between 1 and the length of the string (inclusive) and the iterator should start on the first possible permutation of the given length. For example, new Permuations("abcd", 3) would start iterating on "abc" while newPermutations("abcd", 2) would start iterating on "ab". Invalid parameters should throw an IllegalArgumentException.
- Since the number of permutations grows exponentially with the length of the sequence, your implementation should only use constant storage. In other words, it cannot store any collection that will grow to contain the same number of elements as the number of permutations.Note that according to the above specification, the sequence may begin in the middle of a sequence (depending on the starting length) and still be able to iterate over all of the permutations in the sequence.

I have successfully figured out a way to implement the hasNext() and next() methods from Iterator but I am really struggling with hasPrevious() and previous(). I am attempting to reverse what I am doing when I advance the indexes in the next method by returning the previous element in the sequence and moves the cursor position backwards.  I have been at this for hours and I cannot figure out where I am going wrong. I highly suspect I am significantly over complicating things and there is a much more finessed way to go about this task. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```java
  public Permutations(String sequence, int startingLength) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (sequence == null || sequence.isEmpty()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sequence must not be null or empty.");
    }
    if (startingLength < 1 || startingLength > sequence.length()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
              "Starting length must be between 1 and the length of the sequence.");
    }
    this.input = sequence;
    this.minPermutationLength = startingLength;
    this.maxPermutationLength = sequence.length();
    this.currentLength = startingLength;
    this.indexes = new int[startingLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < startingLength; i++) {
      indexes[i] = i;
    }
    this.hasPrevious = startingLength > 1;
    this.hasNext = true;
    System.out.println("input: " + input);
    System.out.println("startingLength: " + startingLength);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    return hasNext;
  }

  @Override
  public String next() throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (!hasNext) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException("No more permutations available.");
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < currentLength; i++) {
      sb.append(input.charAt(indexes[i]));
    }
    advanceIndexes();
    return sb.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasPrevious() {
    return hasPrevious;
  }

  @Override
  public String previous() throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (!hasPrevious) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException("No previous permutations available.");
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < currentLength; i++) {
      sb.append(input.charAt(indexes[i]));
    }
    regressIndexes();
    System.out.println("previous: " + sb);
    return sb.toString();
  }

  private void advanceIndexes() {
    int i = currentLength - 1;
    while (i >= 0 && indexes[i] == maxPermutationLength - currentLength + i) {
      i--;
    }
    if (i >= 0) {
      indexes[i]++;
      for (int j = i + 1; j < currentLength; j++) {
        indexes[j] = indexes[j - 1] + 1;
      }
    } else {
      if (currentLength < maxPermutationLength) {
        currentLength++;
        indexes = new int[currentLength];
        for (int j = 0; j < currentLength; j++) {
          indexes[j] = j;
        }
      } else {
        hasNext = false;
      }
      hasPrevious = (currentLength > minPermutationLength) || (indexes[0] > 0);
    }
  }

  private void regressIndexes() {
    if (currentLength == minPermutationLength && indexes[0] == 0) {
      hasPrevious = false;
      return;
    }

    int i = currentLength - 1;
    while (i >= 0 && indexes[i] == i) {
      i--;
    }

    if (i >= 0) {
      indexes[i]--;
      for (int j = i + 1; j < currentLength; j++) {
        indexes[j] = maxPermutationLength - currentLength + j;
      }
    } else {
      currentLength--;
      indexes = new int[currentLength];
      for (int j = 0; j < currentLength; j++) {
        indexes[j] = maxPermutationLength - currentLength + j;
      }
      hasPrevious = currentLength != minPermutationLength || indexes[0] > 0;
    }
  }
```

Here is an example console output from a failed test

Test Failed: previous() did not return the correct value expected: t but was: KC
input: KChdt
startingLength: 1
previous: KC

Comment: It sounds like you're partially reinventing `ListIterator`?

Comment: I would create a function that takes an index, and returns a permutation. That reduces the problem to simply keeping the index internally, and being able to add/subtract 1 from it.

Comment: @btilly can you explain that further please

Answer (score 0):

I won't give code for what I think is homework. But I'll explain the strategy.

Suppose that your list of sorted characters is `KCdht`. Which index would produce `KChdt`? Let's count the ones before it.

- We had `5` single element permutations. (BTW these aren't really permutations, but I'll use the same terminology as your question.) Total `5`.
- We had `5*4` 2 element permutations. Total `5+20 = 25`.
- We had `5*4*3` 3 element permutations. Total `60+25 = 85`.
- We had `5*4*3*2` 4 element permutations. Total `120+85 = 205`.
- In the 5 element permutations we haven't yet exhausted `K` first, or `C` first. Total still `205`.
- We had 2 permutations of the form `KCd..`. Total `2+205 = 207`.

And that's it. So there were `207` permutations before, we must be on permutation `208`.

This is called "ranking" the permutation.

Now to move earlier we want permutation `207`. Which means that there `206` before this one.

- We had `5` single element permutations. `206-5 = 201` left.
- We had `5*4` 2 element permutations. `201-20 = 181` left.
- We had `5*4*3` 3 element permutations. Total `181-60 = 121` left.
- We had `5*4*3*2` 4 element permutations. Total `121-120 = 1` left.
- We haven't exhausted the `24` with `K` first, so we start with `K` and have `1` left.
- We haven't exhausted the `6` with `KC` first, so we start with `KC` and have `1` left.
- We haven't exhausted the `2` with `KCh` first, so we start with `KCh` and have `1` left.
- There is one permutation with `KChd` first, so we exhaust that and start with `KCht`.
- The answer is `KChtd`.

This is called unranking the permutation.

So just build functions to find the rank from a permutation, and the permutation from the rank, and then moving forward/backwards can be reduced to adding or subtracting 1.